# How to handle Method Order in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby.  I am familiar with several other languages. My question is about calling methods out of order.  For example:

```
def myfunction
    myfunction2
end

def myfunction2
    puts "in 2"
end
```

How could I call myfunction2 before it is declared? Several languages let you declare it at the top or in a .h file.  How does ruby handle it?

Do I always need to follow this:

```
def myfunction2
    puts "in 2"
end

def myfunction
    myfunction2
end
```

Mainly this bugs me when I need to call another method inside of `def initialize` for a class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can not call a method before you define it. However, that does not mean you can't define `myfunction` before `myfunction2`! Ruby has late binding, so the call to `myfunction2` in `myfunction` will not be associated with the actual `myfunction2` before you call `myfunction`. That means that as long as the first call to `myfunction` is done **after** `myfunction2` is declared, you should be fine.

So, this is ok:

```
def myfunction
    myfunction2
end

def myfunction2
    puts "in 2"
end

myfunction
```

and this is not:

```
def myfunction
    myfunction2
end

myfunction

def myfunction2
    puts "in 2"
end
```

Comment: Note the non-working example can be hammered into working code by adding a `BEGIN` statement: `BEGIN {def myfunction2; puts "in 2";end}`.

Comment: @steenslag An even better approach would be to add an `END` statement: `END{myfunction}`.

Answer (score 7):

The only time method order matters is in purely procedural code, and that's usually short-sighted, given two methods:

```
def greet
  puts "%s, Dave" % random_greeting
end
# If I try to use `greet` here, it'll raise a NoMethodError
def random_greeting
  ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Hallo"].sample
end
# I can use `greet` here, because `random_greeting` is now defiend
```

This would work ok, unless you wanted to use `greet` before `random_greeting` is defined, the way that all non-trivial code solves this is to wrap the behaviour in a class:

```
class Doorman
  def greet
    puts "%s, Dave" % random_greeting
  end
  def random_greeting
    ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Hallo"].sample
  end
end
Doorman.new.greet
```

One can then greet one's guests with `Doorman.new.greet`, by wrapping the behaviour in a class one can model the application better (maybe different objects in your *Hotel* code give different greetings, for example) and it also keeps the `main` namespace clean.

The `main` object in Ruby already has 114 methods defined on it, so it's much better to put your own methods into classes which represent actors or objects in your project's model.

Further to what you said in the question about *in initialize of a class*, this is completely possible:

```
class Doorman
  def initialize
    puts "%s, I'm a new Doorman instance" & random_greeting
  end
  def greet
  "%s, Dave" % random_greeting
  end
  def random_greeting
    ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Hallo"].sample
  end
end
```

Even though the method `random_greeting` isn't defined when we write `initailize`, the whole class is defined before `initialize` is ever called. Again, by wrapping classes, this makes life easier, cleaner and means that things stay [encapsulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is interpreted language so it don't depend on order of functions, example:

```
[1] pry(main)> def myfunction
[1] pry(main)*   myfunction2    
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> 
[3] pry(main)> def myfunction2
[3] pry(main)*   puts "in 2"    
[3] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[4] pry(main)> myfunction
in 2
=> nil
```

Also if, for example, function calls non existing function then runtime exception will be called only if that function will be called, i. e.:

```
[5] pry(main)> def foo
[5] pry(main)*   blubry_starego_marycha
[5] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[6] pry(main)> def boo
[6] pry(main)*   "bom bom bom"
[6] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[7] pry(main)> boo
=> "bom bom bom"
[8] pry(main)> foo
NameError: undefined local variable or method `blubry_starego_marycha' for main:Object
from (pry):9:in `foo'
```

As you see I've declared function `foo` that calls nonexisting function `blubry_starego_marycha` and Ruby is fine with it, it raise exception only if I call `foo`.

Answer (score -1):

You could define method in any order, the order doesn't matter anything.