# Ruby undefined method but method exist

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I am very new to ruby and I am creating a CLI app but I am getting an undefined method error for red_meat and I'm close to being annoyed. How would I define this method if it's already defined or so I thought?

```
def menu
    puts "Are you interested in finding some delicious recipes?"
    puts ""
    puts "Enter yes or no"
    case (gets.chomp.downcase)
    when 'no'
      puts "Aww you missed out on some yummy meals. Thank you for dropping by"
    when 'yes'
      puts "Great! Enter one of the following options (Red meat, Poultry, Seafood or Vegetarian)"
      #case (gets.chomp.downcase)
      input = gets.strip.downcase
      if input = "red meat"
        red_meat
      end
    else
      puts "I'm sorry, are you hangry? Please try again"
      puts ""
      menu
    end

    def red_meat
      puts "red meat recipe 1"
      puts "red meat recipe 2"
      puts "red meat recipe 3"
      puts "red meat recipe 4"
    end
```

The error

```
ERROR: 
cli.rb:22:in `menu': undefined method `red_meat' for #<RecipesCli::CLI:0x00007fd941914228> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your method first to be able to call it later. Inside or outside of your `menu` method.

```rb
def red_meat
    puts "red meat recipe 1"
    puts "red meat recipe 2"
    puts "red meat recipe 3"
    puts "red meat recipe 4"
end 

def menu
    puts "Are you interested in finding some delicious recipes?"
    puts ""
    puts "Enter yes or no"
    case (gets.chomp.downcase)
    when 'no'
      puts "Aww you missed out on some yummy meals. Thank you for dropping by"
    when 'yes'
      puts "Great! Enter one of the following options (Red meat, Poultry, Seafood or Vegetarian)"
      #case (gets.chomp.downcase)
      input = gets.strip.downcase
      if input = "red meat"
        red_meat
      end
    else
      puts "I'm sorry, are you hangry? Please try again"
      puts ""
      menu
    end
end
```

Comment: The problem is only that the method `menu` does not have an `end` statement before the definition of `red_meat` begins, which is why the exception was raised. Obviously you cannot execute `menu` before both methods have been defined, but the order in which the two methods are defined is unimportant.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I assumed that the missing `end` was a copy-paste mistake, as the Error returned would be different if it was the problem. Please try for yourself, [method definition order matters in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10681043/1003472).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the indentation in your code, the method definition for `read_meat` is nested *inside* of the method definition of `menu`.

That means the method definition will only be executed when you call `menu` for the first time. (Actually, it will be executed *every time* you execute `menu`, always overwriting `red_meat` over and over again).

However, since the method definition is at the *end* of `menu` on line 21, the method will not yet be defined when it is called on line 13.

Here is a simplified example:

```rb
def menu
  red_meat

  def red_meat; end
end

menu
# NameError …
```

When you move the method definition to before the call, it works (simplified example):

```rb
def menu
  def red_meat; end

  red_meat
end

menu
```

However, I am guessing that you didn't actually mean to define `red_meat` inside `menu`, so what you probably want is something like this:

```rb
def menu
  red_meat
end

def red_meat; end

menu
```

There is no need to define `red_meat` before defining `menu`. After all, defining `menu` doesn't call `read_meat`, only *calling* `menu` calls `red_meat`. So, all you need to ensure is that `red_meat` is defined before you *call* `menu`.

Hint: if you use an editor with automatic code formatting, you would immediately see that the `def red_meat` is indented with respect to the `def menu`, indicating that the definition `red_meat` is nested inside the body of `menu`.

Note: there's at least one other bug in your code.

Comment: I'm wondering how you can have 2 downvotes in an answer like this. I see no problem with it.